# Ошибка при создании скрипта

Tags: c#, unity3d

При создании нового скрипта юнити пишет "No MonoBehaivour scripts in the file, or their names do not match the file name".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если реимпортировать все ассеты, каждый скрипт получит такую ошибку, даже которые были рабочими.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Этот лог говорит о том, что либо в файле нет наследника MonoBehaivour, либо имя класса-наследника не совпадает с именем файла (у монобеха это обязательное условие).

Это не ошибка, а скорее предупреждение. Если вы попытаетесь повесить класс на объект - вот тогда вам выдаст ошибку) но имя класса совпадает. Так что проблем, по идее, быть не должно.

Comment: По началу проблемы не было, она возникла внезапно и теперь любые созданные скрипты пишут такое предупреждение и не могут вешаться на объекты в сцене.

Comment: @bot_xD, хм. попробуйте закрыть Unity, удалить папки Library и Temp(если сама не удалится). После этого снова открыть проект. И у вас, случаем, никаких ошибок в консоли сейчас не висит? Возможно проект недокомпилировался просто.

Comment: Исправил всё созданием нового проекта, а старый к чертям удалил